# In SwiftUI, how can we reuse a set of modifiers or make them into a kind of component to not repeatedly call them?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In SwiftUI we may have many pieces of code like this:

```
Text("Hello World")
  .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3, leading: 3, bottom: 3, trailing: 3))
  .background(Color.blue)
  .cornerRadius(5)
```

However, as you or any other very experienced and professional developers may aware, we want to stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and absolutely don't want to re-write the modifiers:

```
.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3, leading: 3, bottom: 3, trailing: 3))
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(5)
```

for every `Text(...)` or `Button` or any other SwiftUI component.

It would be better to wrap the:

```
.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3, leading: 3, bottom: 3, trailing: 3))
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(5)
```

in some kind of method or reusable component. I know how to do it in UIKit, but the question is how do we do that in SwiftUI's declarative way to build GUIs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is how it is usually done with custom `ViewModifier`, plus depicts example of how it could be configured via parameters:

```
struct MyTextModifier: ViewModifier {
    let corner: CGFloat
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3, leading: 3, bottom: 3, trailing: 3))
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(corner)
    }
}

extension View {
    func configured(with radius: CGFloat = 5) -> some View {
        self.modifier(MyTextModifier(corner: radius))
    }
}

struct MyTextModifier_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
            .configured()
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.2, iOS 13.2

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to group modifiers for reuse is to declare them in an extension on `View`:

```
extension View {

    func customStyle() -> some View {
        self.padding(3)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(5)
    }
}
```

then you can just simply use it like this:

```
Text("Hello World").customStyle()
```

This will only work when all of the modifiers can be applied to View. When you want to group modifiers specific to `Image` you would have to do it in an extension on `Image` etc.

Answer (score 5):

I would create every component as a view, instead of an extension. That way you can always preview the component and have a central repository of 'reusable' components:

```
struct customText : View {

 let text: String

 var body: some View {

  Text(string)
   .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 3, leading: 3, bottom: 3, trailing: 3))
   .background(Color.blue)
   .cornerRadius(5)
  }
}
```

Append a preview to the above and you can always view exactly what your text will look like in the preview canvas, making future edits easier.

And to use:

```
customText(text: "Hello World")
```

You can still add modifiers to its use. You can then have a single source of views which can be used throughout your app (different text types, buttons, etc).

Comment: Unrelated to ability to preview - see other answer

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [Group](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group):

#### Before:

```swift
GoogleAuthUI()
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .disabled(isLoading)
    .opacity(isLoading ? 0.5 : 1)

AppleAuthUI()
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .disabled(isLoading)
    .opacity(isLoading ? 0.5 : 1)
```

#### After:

```swift
Group {
    GoogleAuthUI()
    AppleAuthUI()
}
.padding(.horizontal)
.disabled(isLoading)
.opacity(isLoading ? 0.5 : 1)
```